# I want to change the the value using for loop

Tags: python, django

hi guys I am actually having trouble with my codes. my codes are like this.

```
{% for activity in activityDoneList %}
    <tr>
       <td><a href="{% url 'activity:update' activity.pk %}">{{ activity.title }}</a> </td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.status }}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{mission.name}}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.time_from }}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.time_to }}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.date_exec }}</td>
    </tr>          
    {% endfor %}
```

for example. that activity.status would be integers such as 1, 2, 3.
All I want is to have an output instead of showing those numbers, it will just by like:

```
if activity.status==1: 
      activity.status="Done" 
elif activity.status ==2: 
      activity.status="Running" 
else: 
      activity.status =="Not Yet"
```

Please help me code this.

Comment: Maybe select widget would be good for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for activity in activityDoneList %}
    <tr>
       <td><a href="{% url 'activity:update' activity.pk %}">{{ activity.title }}</a> </td>
       {% if activity.status == 1 %}
         <td width="10%">Done</td>
       {% elif activity.status == 2 %}
         <td width="10%">Running</td>
       {% else %}
         <td width="10%">Done</td>
       {% endif %}
       <td width="10%">{{mission.name}}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.time_from }}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.time_to }}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.date_exec }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

this will accomplish what you are looking for but it's fairly sloppy. It would be better to have this done on your server somewhere. This isn't really what Jinja is for.

You could also use Javascript to change the value but this could break if your users have JS disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of a template tag.

**activity_tags.py**

```
from django import template    

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def get_activity_status_value(status):
    if status==1:
        value="Done"
    elif status ==2:
        value="Running"
    else:
        value ="Not Yet"
    return value
```

`get_activity_status_value` template tag takes activity status as parameter and returns the appropriate value depending on the value of status.

Then in your template, you can just use this template tag directly and pass it `activity.status` and appropriate value will be displayed.

```
{% load activity_tags %}

{% for activity in activityDoneList %}
    <tr>
       <td><a href="{% url 'activity:update' activity.pk %}">{{ activity.title }}</a> </td>
       <td width="10%">{% get_activity_status_value activity.status %}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{mission.name}}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.time_from }}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.time_to }}</td>
       <td width="10%">{{ activity.date_exec }}</td>
    </tr>          
{% endfor %}
```